# how scrape image using jsoup?

Tags: java, jsoup

So im trying to scrape the QRcode image src from a webpage using `jsoup` but its not working. Whenever i try to `println(elements.attr("src"))` it just prints `""` a blank string.

> This is the webpage: https://app.ethiomobilemoney.et:2121/ammwebpay/#/?transactionNo=202207131604471547205398120337410

**Code:**

```java
private class description_webscrape extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
    @Override
    public Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        Document document = null;
        try {
            document = Jsoup.connect("https://app.ethiomobilemoney.et:2121/ammwebpay/#/?transactionNo=202207131604471547205398120337410").get();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Elements elements = document.selectXpath("/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/img");
        System.out.println(elements.attr("src"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Define "not working".

Comment: There's no real way to help w/ the information provided. It's also possible the QR code is generated after the initial page load. IIRC JSoup isn't a browser emulator, meaning elements added/modified via JS would be inaccessible. (JSoup may have changed since I used it last, though.) Since I can't access the website (perhaps others can) there's not much else I can offer.

Comment: @DaveNewton what do you mean I cant access the website?

Comment: the provided link is not reachable

Comment: @DaveNewton is there any other workaround that you would use? or any other library that could do what I'm trying to achieve? or do you know any api that scrapes data from a webpage and returns it?

Comment: Requests for libraries, APIs, frameworks, etc. are off-topic on SO, but searching the web should be sufficient. It's impossible to know why it doesn't work with the information provided (although I *suspect* the QR code is generated after the initial DOM rendering).

Comment: @Eritrean hey brother I'm Ethiopian, nice to see my people around. Is the link not opening?

Comment: Selam wendmé, endemen amesheh. Link dosen't work. At least for me. But if the site uses JavaScript, which is very likey, Jsoup is not going to work anyway. Try using [htmlunit](https://htmlunit.sourceforge.io/gettingStarted.html)